# How to get Image uploads in HTML to be of ratio 1:1

Tags: html, django, image

I am using the Django framework to allow drivers to register with my site, and one of the fields that they need to submit is a picture of themselves.

A snippet of code from forms.py...

```
your_picture = forms.ImageField(help_text="A picture of yourself so that we know who you are")
```

I want to make sure always that the user inputs an image that is 1:1. Especially when it comes to mobile devices and the user selects an already available picture, I need it to allow the user to crop it as a 1:1, like how I have seen in many different applications.

I want to know how I can do a client-side check and a server-side validation to see if the image meets my requirements.

Just for your information, the images are stored and uploaded into AWS S3.

Any support would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `pillow` package.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('whatever.png')
width, height = im.size

if width == height:
    print("Ok!!")
else:
    print("Invalid image.")
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I check it in the client-side?